# how to hide source folder of magento when i inspect

Tags: magento

I want to hide source folder and file of magento when I inspect.

I checked other magento not showing source folder and files. Show source folder when I use inspect element in browser.

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: i want say when i use inspect element of browser in sources shows all the folder of my website. i want to hide that folder on inspect element of browser.

Comment: Please see the attachment image